# sp_execute_remote sometimes fails to return - why? / workarounds

Tags: azure-sql-database, sp-executesql

I have an extensive Azure SQL stored proc, called periodically from Azure Data Factory, which is querying another Azure SQL database in the same region using `sp_execute_remote`. 99.5% of the time this works fine but, on some occasions, the call to `sp_execute_remote` never returns.

Access to the external resource is via a database scoped credential using a native SQL login granting read only permissions. The call is of the form

```
insert into ##newrecs exec [sp_execute_remote] @external_server, @stmt, <params>
```

I have asked the DBA to take a look at what is running on the external database when the hang occurs, but he says he can't see anything amiss. Nothing we are aware of coincides with the failure.

The calling process shows Status RUNNABLE and command EXECUTE. Looking at sys.dm_tran_locks shows that my process has locks on the stored credentials and the temp table for the results. Nothing else has locks on the same resources.

If I capture the @stmt and fire off the same remote query "manually", it returns just fine.

Has anyone any thoughts on

1. Why this might be occurring
2. How to detect/recover the situation from the calling end
3. How to delve deeper into diagnosis on the "remote" Azure database (which is the production environment of a finance system, so I can't mess around too much with it).

Comment: Did you check the remarks from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azuresqldb-current#remarks)?

Comment: Yes, thanks: the document summarises the "rules" and I am meeting the rules. The same call works 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a bug in Azure SQL. After support escalation, Microsoft fixed this around Dec 2021.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).